# confidence interval for FindFit

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I have a system of delay differential equations

```
p = 99741 + 17167;
aa = 5;
bb = 10;

equationS = s'[t] == -b s[t] i[t]/p;
equationE = e'[t] == b s[t] i[t]/p - \[Sigma] e[t - aa];
equationI = i'[t] == \[Sigma] e[t - aa] - \[Gamma] i[t - bb];
equationR = r'[t] == \[Gamma] i[t - bb];
```

This is the data I use to fit the system to real data. I have 61 datapoints

```
infected = {7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5, 25, 44, 86, 116, 176, 196, 269, 404, 632, 921, 1178, 1370, 1739, 2221, 2803, 3570, 4396, 5284, 6473, 6953, 8268, 9328, 10575, 12310, 13144, 16796, 17923, 20002, 22511, 25269, 29561, 30366, 33599, 39161, 42022, 41290, 61650, 66955, 68578, 71849, 79404, 80827, 82333, 86740, 89431, 91012, 94094, 98769, 99741};

Some parameters I have

 \[Gamma] = 1/10;
 \[Sigma] = 1/5;
  totaltime = 190;
```

I set the dataset as

```
dataset1 = {Range[61], infected} // Transpose;
```

and

```
model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{equationS, equationE, equationI, equationR, s[0] == p, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0, e[0] ==  1}, i, {t, 0, totaltime}, {b}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", MaxSteps -> Infinity];
```

and 
    fit = FindFit[dataset1, model[b][t], {{b, 0.5}}, t]

I tried to find the confidence interval and standard deviation but I could not. I also have the following error line;

```
ParametricNDSolveValue::ihist: Conditions given at t$677 = 0.` will be interpreted as initial history functions for t$677/;t$677<=0
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Avoid `FindFit` and use `NonlinearModelFit`.  The latter gets you lots of necessary summary statistics and (essentially) uses the same input structure.

Comment: @JimB tried it as well and it gives FittedModel[InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,190.}},<>][t]. It gives zero and I do not know why.

Comment: You have two question:  (1) How do I get confidence intervals? and (2) Why does my code not work?  I only addressed the first question.

Comment: Your code works fine (when using `NonlinearModelFit`).  What you see are "warnings" rather than "errors".  (Although the warnings should be heeded.)  You end up with a fit so poor that I don't think getting confidence intervals would be very useful.  Try `fit = NonlinearModelFit[dataset1, model[b][t], {{b, 0.5}}, t];
Show[ListPlot[dataset1],
 Plot[fit[t] // Quiet, {t, 1, 61}], PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you solved it.  But might you supply an answer?  It's OK to answer one's own questions.

Comment: I wrote another code to solve the problem. I have no more the warnings but still work for the confidence interval. Once done, I will edit the question and give the answer for the community. Thanks!